# Extension of flux to higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

I'm UG physics student. So sorry if this question is dumb.

We are in phase space of $6N$ dimensions. Each point $ \mathbf r$ in this space has $6N$ coordinates.

[image]
*Pathria, Statistical mechanics* writes

> Consider an arbitrary "volume" $\omega$ in the relevant region of the phase space and let the "surface" enclosing this volume be denoted by $\sigma$; then the net rate at which the representative points "flow" out of $\omega$ (across the bounding surface $\sigma$ ) is given by
> $$
> \int \rho \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{n}} d \sigma
> $$

Where $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a **generalized** velocity of those representative points inside this volume and $\rho$ is their number density function

I can understand why the equation is true if the velocity is a spatial 3D vector, and the surface is a regular 3D one, however in higher dimensions I'm not sure what the equation means and why it holds. We can't even visualize a surface so what does it mean that representative points flow out of a surface?

Can anyone please explain the equation above.

Thank you

Comment: Does it make sense in 2D that if a constant vector field creates a flow, then the rate at which flow goes across a line is characterized by the scalar projection of the velocity vector onto the line's normal vector? Does it make sense that the same is true in 3D for planes, and that adding a dimension to go from 2D to 3D doesn't change this characterization? Can you convince yourself that going from 3D to higher dimensions (and hyperplanes) doesn't change anything? This is the local (hence linear) versions of what's going on (assuming constant density for simplicity).

Comment: I can convince myself that the form of the equation remains same if one goes from 2D to 3D , however how can one say with absolute certainty that it holds in higher dimensions?

Comment: How did you convince yourself from 2D to 3D?